# AddThis on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, addthis

I have this AddThis:

```
<a class="addthis_button addthis_default_style">Share Site</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=myid">
</script>
```

Looking good everywhere ...When clicked, I get the modal box/pop box with my sharing links...but when I click on iPad nothing happens...anyone know how to get this resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I get running that code in the iPad simulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/01PbQ.png

Can you point me to a URL where you're running this code? The issue might be with how our code interacts with other elements on your page.

Comment: Thanks Paul I think I found the issue...at20mc div { display: none;}..I think i did this because it was giving me issues with accesability (Tab Key gets stuck once it reaches addthis pop box). For now I commented it out and well rereview the accesability issue